# VBA Macro to extract multiple values from a table based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked at many of the macros but did not see one that I could use, so I am seeking help.

I am trying to extract a select group of components with associated componentParents from sheet1.

On sheet1 (Tab1), in columns A and B, I have Component and ComponentParent respectively. Component is used by more than one componentParent. There are close to 60,000 component/componentParents.

On sheet2 (Tab2) I have specific components in column A (criteria). There are close to 1200 components. These are only a part of the components included in Tab1.

On sheet3 (Tab3), using the components in Tab2, I want to output in column A and B respectively, the component and ComponentParents that match each criterion in Tab2. For example my worksheets should look as follows:

Sheet1 (Tab1)
Col A  ( Component) ;          Col B (ComponentParent)

Sheet 2 (Tab2)
Col A (Component)

Sheet 3 (Tab3)
Col A ( Component )  ;          Col B (Component/Parent1, Component/Parent2)

I only want a match for the components in Tab2.

I am using Excel 2013.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sir. Please take a quick look at our [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and reformat your question accordingly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Please rework your question to make it more clear. What are `Component/Parent1` and `Component/Parent2`, and how do they differ from `ComponentParent` on Sheet1?
Are you intent to copy the rows from Sheet1 to Sheet3, which are listed on Sheet2?

Comment: Please disregard my inquiry. I have done the extract using Advanced Filter and created this macro:Sub EXTRACT()
'
' EXTRACT Macro
' EXTRACT DATA FROM TAB1 TO TAB3 BASED ON CRITERIA ON TAB2
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
    Sheets("Tab1").Range("A1:B47802").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Tab2").Range("A1:A1189"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:B1" _
        ), Unique:=True
End Sub